# What do leaves mean in Blood on the Clocktower?

Tags: blood-on-the-clocktower

In the game [Blood on the Clocktower](https://bloodontheclocktower.com/), some of the role tokens have green leaves on the west/north/east side of the token. There are also some tokens who have a larger orange leaf.

1 west and 2 north: [image]

1 east: [image]

An icon with the orange leaf: [image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The different leaf icons (and number of leaves) are reminders for the storyteller.

Green leaves indicate tokens the storyteller needs to add to the game during setup for the character, while an orange leaf means the character alters the normal setup for the character or game.

From [the Blood on the Clocktower wiki](https://wiki.bloodontheclocktower.com/Glossary):

> Leaf: The small green and orange symbols on many character tokens that help the Storyteller run the game. Green leaves on the top show the number of reminder tokens to add to the Grimoire. A green leaf on the left shows that the character needs a night token on the first night. A green leaf on the right shows that the character needs a night token on each night except the first. An orange leaf means that the character setup is different than normal for this game.